# Is there a SQL table constraint to ensure that a relationship exists between two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

```
CREATE TABLE leagues (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE players (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE league_members (
    league_id INTEGER REFERENCES leagues (id),
    player_id INTEGER REFERENCES players (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (league_id, player_id)
);

CREATE TABLE games (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    league_id INTEGER REFERENCES leagues (id),
    winner INTEGER REFERENCES players (id),
    loser INTEGER REFERENCES players (id)
);
```

In the games table, is there a constraint I can use that will check to make sure that the winner and loser are both members of the same league?

For example:

players table:

```
---- id ---- first_name ----
     1       "John"
     2       "Joe"
     3       "Jill"
```

leagues table:

```
---- id ---- name ----
     1       "League 1"
     2       "League 2"
```

league_members table:

```
---- id ---- league_id ---- player_id ----
     1           1              1
     2           1              2
     3           2              3
```

I want to make sure that in the games table the following would cause an error:

```
INSERT INTO games (league_id, winner, loser) VALUES (1,1,3);
```

This shouldn't be allowed since player 3 isn't in league 1. Right now I'm just running this query on the league_members table:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM league_members WHERE league_id = 1 AND (player_id = 1 OR player_id = 3);
```

and them making sure count is 2, which means both players are members of the league with id 1. If the count is 2 then I allow the insertion into the games table, otherwise I don't. Is there a way to do this but have the database handle the constraint so that I don't have to do the extra query before I try to insert into the games table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of foreign keys should keep things straight:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    league_id INTEGER REFERENCES leagues (id),
    winner INTEGER REFERENCES players (id),
    loser INTEGER REFERENCES players (id),
    constraint FK_League_Winner FOREIGN KEY (league_id,winner)
       REFERENCES league_members (league_id,player_id),
    constraint FK_League_Loser FOREIGN KEY (league_id,loser)
       REFERENCES league_members (league_id,player_id)
);
```

Because both of these keys are sharing the `league_id` column in this table, there cannot be a situation where the members are from different leagues.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!